# Play 2.5 (Java): Default form in template

Tags: playframework-2.5

As of Play 2.5 `FromFactory` needs to be injected to generate a new `Form`.
That works perfectly in a Controller.

However I would like to create an empty default form in my template. This used to work like this:

```
Form.form(classOf[Foo]).fill(new Foo()))
```

Of course `Form.form` is deprecated and I want to switch to FormFactory. However I have no idea how to inject FormFactory in a template.

There is a similar use-case for accessing the Configuration. For the Configuration it works by simply calling `ConfigFactory.load()`. However FormFactory does not seem to have a load function.

Comment: What is the reason behind? Can't you just pass the empty form to the template as a parameter? You should avoid putting logic in the Twirl templates.

Comment: The reason is that we are using AJAX to submit the form - the form html  is reloaded on submit. In that case the form object is indeed passed to the template as a parameter - from the form controller. 

However we want to show the form component by just including the template on several different subpages and it is really cumbersome to pass the empty form object through all the pages and components everywhere. So we just created a default empty form for the template parameter in case it is not set explicitly.